# Getting error .tab is not a function in asp.net

Tags: jquery

I have this error in console :

```
TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function
 at fire (jquery-1.7.1.js:1046)
 at Object.fireWith (jquery-1.7.1.js:1164)
 at Function.ready (jquery-1.7.1.js:435)
 at HTMLDocument.DOMContentLoaded (jquery-1.7.1.js:923)
```

and my jQuery code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () { 
   var tabName = 
            $("[id*=TabName]").val() != "" ? 
            $("[id*=TabName]").val() : 
            "employment"; 
   $('#Tabs a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show'); 
   $("#Tabs a").click(function () { 
    $("[id*=TabName]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", "")); }); 
  }); 
 }); 
</script>
```

and it's HTML code is :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/datatables.min.css"/>
```

Comment: can you please add some codes?(Html code and jquery)

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: You're trying to invoke some plugin that provides `.tab` but it doesn't work. Most likely, you don't have the plugin added, or jQuery is loaded after it.

Comment: <asp:HiddenField ID="TabName" runat="server" />

Comment: `.tab('show')` is not built in function. I don't exactly understand but I think you want  `show()` instead of that.

Answer (score 0):

jquery is Case_Sensitive.You must type "tabs" not "Tabs".

Please use this :

```
  $('#tabs a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show'); 
   $("#tabs a").click(function () { 
    $("[id*=TabName]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", "")); }); 
  })
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Please give feedback -@Tipu

Comment: "Tabs" is id of div  <div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">